# How to take payment in MATIC on polygon testnet

Tags: ether, ethers.js, polygon

I am using polygon testnet to deploy my smart contract and ethers.js to interact with it. I have stored the price required to do a particular transaction in the smart contract as 0.001 ETH but when I try to do this transaction using ethers.js by sending an object containing {value: 0.001}, the value required on metamask is 0.001 MATIC instead of the corresponding value for 0.001 ETH. How do I make this happen?

Comment: You need to use Wrapped Ether token. But it is more complicated. Easier to use the native token which is matic

Answer (score 0):

Since the Matic / Eth conversion rate is dynamic you need a price feed to convert it on demand on chain from a verifiable source.
Oracles does the job for you
[chainlink's matic-defi-price-feed](https://blog.chain.link/matic-defi-price-feeds/)